How can the Church Thesis be true?
The Church Thesis asserts that every total function is computable.
We can view a total function $\Bbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$ as a binary expansion of a number in $[0, 1]$. In this way, to every number in $[0, 1]$ corresponds at least one such function.
Those functions are total, which according to the Church Thesis means they are computable.
In particular, the Omega Chaitin number is in $[0, 1]$, so its digits are recursively enumerable, so it is computable. This is a contradiction, because the Omega Chaitin number is not computable.
What am I missing? Surely my argument is wrong in some way.

This answer seems very related, specifically the first point.


It is consistent with the constructive analysis that every real is computable, does this mean that the constructive $\Bbb{R}$ does not contain Chaitin's Omega?


"every total function is computable" No, it doesn't. CT says that every effectively calculable function (total or not) is computable.

It looks like you're conflating Church's thesis CT and the principle of constructive mathematics with the same name (which I'll call "$CT_C$" here). This is an understandable source of confusion, but it's important to keep them separate. I'm not an expert in constructive mathematics, but certainly in contexts where $CT_C$ holds it should be the case that "Chaitin's Omega doesn't exist" is, phrased appropriately, true. However, that has no bearing on the truth of classical CT in classically-construed reality.

@NoahSchweber If I might ask, then is the wiki page misleading? It differentiates between the Church-Turing thesis (that every effectively calculable function is computable) and the Church thesis (that every total function is computable, albeit only in constructive mathematics it seems). I am not really well versed in constructive mathematics, so any insight is helpful for me (and I believe the OP) too.

@NoahSchweber Perhaps I should have clarified, I am merely talking about $CT_C$. Is the set ${0, 1}^\Bbb{N}$ different in constructive and classical mathematics? If so the issue in my argument is pretty clear.

@Eolien55 Yes, they're - at least potentially, since there are many versions of constructive mathematics - quite different.

@HackR I would say that the wiki page is borderline misleading (which isn't that rare tbh).

Fair enough @NoahSchweber Thank you!

Well, the effective topos gives a model of Church's principle (which is what I usually call it, to avoid confusion with the Church-Turing thesis). So let's look at what happens there. Someone with more raw computability experience can correct me if I'm mistaken about that aspect.

We can view a total function $ℕ→\{0,1\}$ as a binary expansion of a number in $[0,1]$.

Yes, you can do this. There is a function from binary expansions to real numbers, $\langle - \rangle : 2^ℕ → ℝ$. Keep in mind that these are computable binary expansions and computable reals (i.e. each is represented by machines that compute relevant data, and the function operates on representations of these machines).

In this way, to every number in [0,1] corresponds at least one such function.

This, I believe, is not correct, depending on what you mean. There is no computable mapping that accepts computable reals and produces computable binary expansions, even if we do not care about the mapping being extensional. This is due to 'infinite carry' problems. Certain machines may approximate real (rational, actually) numbers in ways that it is never clear whether you may output a $0$ or a $1$ for certain positions in the binary expansion. So, the statement
$$∀x:ℝ. ∃α:2^ℕ. \langle α \rangle = x$$
is not constructively valid.
The best you can do is to say that every real doesn't not have a binary expansion. Or, every real isn't distinct from all binary expansions.
$$∀x:ℝ. ¬ ∀α:2^ℕ. \langle α \rangle \neq x$$

In particular, the Omega Chaitin number is in [0,1]

This is also not true. The quick way to know is that $ℝ$ in the effective topos consists of the computable reals, and Chaitin's number is not computable. For the Cauchy definition, presumably there is no computable Cauchy approximation to the number. I'm uncertain what would be the problem from a Dedekind perspective; possibly it cannot be located.
So, two of your assertions are (I think) not constructively valid, and are false in the effective topos.

Yes, my construction and arguments were built using classical logic and standard analysis & set theory. I somehow thought I could take these objects and put them in a constructive context without problems, but I believe you've highlighted them all. Thank you!
